# how to check if an Input values is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Ajax Begin form :-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AssignUsers", "SecurityGroup", 


    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "UsersAssignment"//,
   // LoadingElementId = "progress",
   // OnSuccess = "reenable"
}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.GroupID)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<p>Search  <input  placeholder="Search by name.." name="selectedUserNames" type="text" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "SecurityGroup")" /> </p>

<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

But the problem is that is the user did not enter any value in the Test Input field, then an empty sting will be passed ato the database. so how i can check if the array contains empty string or not.

The action method which will handle the view is :-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AssignUsers(int GroupID, string[] selectedUserNames, string[] currentUserNames)
        { try
            {if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {repository.AssignUserGroup(GroupID, selectedUserNames, currentUserNames);
                    repository.Save();
                    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = GroupID });
                    }
                    else if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {var ADUsers = repository.GetADUsers(null);
                        var group = repository.FindAllGroup(GroupID);
                        PopulateAssignedUsersData(group, ADUsers);
                        return PartialView("_Group", group);
```

and the repository method is :-

```
public void AssignUserGroup(int id, string[] selectedUsers, string[] currentusernames)
        {
            var usergroups = tms.UserGroups.Where(a=>a.GroupID == id);
            foreach (var ug in usergroups)
            {
                if (currentusernames != null)
                {for (int c = 0; c < currentusernames.Count(); c++)
                    {if (ug.UserName == currentusernames[c])
                        {tms.UserGroups.Remove(ug);
                        }}}}
                if( selectedUsers !=null){
               for (int i = 0; i < selectedUsers.Count(); i++)
               {UserGroup usergroup = new UserGroup();
                   usergroup.GroupID = id;
                   usergroup.UserName = selectedUsers[i];
                   tms.UserGroups.Add(usergroup);} } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
 if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace ( your string; for example : currentusernames[c] ) ) 
 {
    -- do something or throw an exception--
 }   

 else
 {
   -- do something else --
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your inputs at some point.  This is usually done with the model, and then subsequently checking the `ModelState`. However, as you have complex properties being generated, it might be better for you to validate the inputs further into the program.

Update you repository method to validate the parameters supplied to it.

```
public void AssignUserGroup(int id, string[] selectedUsers, string[] currentusernames)
{
    if (id < 1) throw new ArgumentExpcetion("id");
    if (selectedUsers.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("selectedUsers");
    if (currentusernames.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("currentusernames");

    var usergroups = tms.UserGroups.Where(a=>a.GroupID == id);

    // May need to user .Count instead of .Length
    if (usergroups == null || usergroups.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id");

    foreach (var ug in usergroups)
    {
       if (currentusernames != null)
       {
          for (int c = 0; c < currentusernames.Count(); c++)
          {
              if (ug.UserName == currentusernames[c])
              {
                  tms.UserGroups.Remove(ug);
              }
          }
       }
    }

    if( selectedUsers !=null)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < selectedUsers.Count(); i++)
       {
           UserGroup usergroup = new UserGroup();
           usergroup.GroupID = id;
           usergroup.UserName = selectedUsers[i];
               tms.UserGroups.Add(usergroup);
       }
    }
}
```

And then update your controller to handle the various expected exceptions.

```
try
{
   repository.AssignUserGroup(GroupID, selectedUserNames, currentUserNames);
} catch (Exception e)
{
   if (e is ArgumentException || e is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
   {
       return redirect("Error");// Show an error view or message etc
   }

   throw; // Allow other exceptions to bubble
}
```